# Pushing to Heroku not updating my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, deploying

I'm using Heroku to deploy my rails app. But when I commit to git and push to Heroku, some things don't update from my local app. Some CSS and AJAX stuff mostly from what i can tell.

I've ran `git status` and there's nothing to commit. I didn't receive any errors from Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

I had to precompile assets before deploying.